# How to open a Chrome page in full screen (not just maximized, like actually f11 type full screen) using Batch

Tags: google-chrome, batch-file, youtube

For reference I am very new to anything programming stuff.
I am trying to open "https://www.youtube.com/tv#/" in full screen using a batch file.
The Batch file also needs to open another chrome tab a few seconds before opening "https://www.youtube.com/tv#/" because a chrome extension needs to load that prevents youtube TV from redirecting to normal youtube (which allows me to cast to my pc from my phone)

no matter what I tried so far I only got it to open the window in a maximized window, not in fullscreen.

If doing this in another language would be easier, I would be glad to switch instead, but I have absolutely 0 idea how to write any other language so help would be appreciated :)

```
@Echo off

start /MAX "" https://www.youtube.com/
timeout /t 2
start /MAX "" https://www.youtube.com/tv#/
```

This is my current batch file
I tried --start-fullscreen afterwards but it didnt work either, might just also have used it wrong.

Comment: You should focus on improving your skills to find useful pages in world wide web. A simple search with a www search engine using `Chrome command line options` results in lots of links to useful pages like [List of Chromium Command Line Switches](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) with the option `--start-fullscreen`. Searching for `Chrome full screen start` results in lots of links to pages with definitely containing the information you are asking for here on Stack Overflow completely off-topic as not related to programming and program code at all.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:
Close all chrome windows and then:

`start "" chrome --start-fullscreen "https://www.youtube.com/"`